# How long would the St. Louis arch stand if humanity vanished from the earth, tomorrow?

Tags: science-based

How long would the [St. Louis arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_Arch) stand if humanity vanished from the earth, tomorrow?  What would be the failure mechanism?

Note:  I'm following the directions to ask a specific question, but if it's too particular to be interesting, generalize it to other iconic structure durations.

Comment: Depends upon when there is another [big earthquake in the area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1811%E2%80%9312_New_Madrid_earthquakes).

Comment: Welcome! Please take a moment to check out our [tour] and [help] and [What's This Place All About?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) --- here you can find out what kinds of questions we take here and what kinds of questions we don't take. We're here to help you build your *fictional world*, not to satisfy your idle curiosity about places or sites in the real world.

Comment: A minimum of courtesy would have required that the name [St. Louis Arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_Arch) be hyperlinked to a Wikipedia article or some other source of basic information about the [folly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folly) in question. Many of us are not intimately familiar with American monumental art.

Comment: @elemtilas This seems on-topic, if not directly stated. "How far in the future do I need to set my world for this iconic structure to have collapsed due to natural causes after maintenance ends?" seems like a valid justification for asking here.

Comment: @Frostfyre - A stretch, in my opinion, but I see your point.

Comment: @Frostfyre For me it show lack of basic reasearch that would give answer to such question. Worldbuilding would be "What I need to change to have Arch stand more then XXX stated in this data".

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY While I agree the question could have been answered through independent research, I'll also point out that "lack of basic research" is a reason to downvote, not to close, which is what my original comment was regarding after coming across this question in the review queue.

Answer (score 3):

There was a documentary on this subject. 250 years, barring an earthquake was their estimate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_After_People  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHYRcokSsek

Comment: BTW this ans similar shows cover most major world monuments. Very good science.

Comment: That's pretty lousy engineering, then,  compared with, say some of the European castles dating back a good ten centuries!   Or maybe   Lifetime is inversely proportional to height of structure.....

Comment: I suppose it's about goals. The arch is meant to be spectacular and beautiful as it's primary function, and steel is strong but not environmentally resistant. On the other hand, abandoned castles without human maintenance start looking pretty rough pretty fast. https://www.google.com/search?q=castle+ruins&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=ubAAvqGHx3fe_M%253A%252CWVAOI6sN098uoM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTSn1_yfdtSRSF8BpPv20wX6IawHw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPiNHNs5_pAhVWGM0KHVbGCZAQ9QEwC3oECAUQRg#imgrc=ubAAvqGHx3fe_M:

Comment: @CarlWitthoft And European castles can't hold a candle to the Great Pyramids when it comes to grandeur and longevity, but that didn't stop them from making them. Also, there is something to be said for the height difference between the arch's 192 m versus the 55 m of Chateau de Coucy (tallest medieval castle tower according to Guinness World Records).